# Print json to file from ruby program

Tags: ruby, json, file, io

I have a command line application. the way to call it is :

```
ruby comb.rb --format json 'journals.csv' 'articles.csv' 'authors.json' > full_articles.json
```

Basically what it does is combining information from different files (the ones you pass as arguments). The format defines the format of the output.

An array of arrays arribes to the json presenter class (collection in the snipped).

I want to insert to a new file(the one I pass as the last argument) a json object (an array of objects).

This is part of the presenter class:

```
def call
      collection.each do |line|
        puts as_json line
      end
    end

    private

    def as_json line
      {
        "issn"    => line[0],
        "title"   => line[1],
        "doi"     => line[2],
        "author"  => line[3],
        "journal" => line[4]
      }
    end
```

The input I get to the `full_articles.json`file is a set of objects but not encapsulated inside an array. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "a set of objects but not encapsulated inside an array." ?

Comment: @rohit89

the file looks like:
{...} \n
{...} \n
{...}

Comment: And you want it to be as `[{...}, {...}, {...}]` ?

Comment: @rohit89 yes, this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as an array, you can use `map`

```
puts collection.map {|line| as_json line}.inspect
```

or

```
puts collection.map {|line| as_json line}.to_json
```

Comment: Same output as before. @rohit89

Comment: Wait, is this supposed to be in json?

Comment: It has to be in a Json format, but not stringified. @rohit89

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
puts collection.map {|line| as_json line}.inspect
```

The way @rohit89 it was right but the array was not shown. Whit inspect it is shown.